# Iterate through 'middle' model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

all,

I'm relatively new to Rails and need a little help please.

I'm trying to iterate through 'Chorelists' which contains IDs for both 'Users' and 'Chores'. The associations for chores and users is 'has_many' and the one for chorelists is 'belongs_to' both of the others. Chorelists are saving well (the console bears this out) with the right IDs for users and chores, but I can't figure out the syntax to iterate through them in the 'savelist#display' view.

Any help would be most appreciated!

```
class SaveListController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index

@chorelist = Chorelist.create(user_id: params[:user_id], chore_id: params[:chore_id])

redirect_to pick_chores_path

end


def display

@chorelist = Chorelist.all

@user = User.find(current_user.id)

end

end
```

What would you put in the .each to iterate through the current user's chorelist to get the actual chore names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Chorelist` is functioning as a "join" model; its purpose is to join a `User` with a `Chore`.

To get a list of `Chores` for a given `User`, you'll want to set up a `has_many :through` relationship in the `User` model.

```
class User
  has_many :chorelists
  has_many :chores, through: :chorelists
end

class Chorelist
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :chore
end
```

With this setup, the `User` model will gain a `chores` collection which you can iterate over.

```
<ul>
  <% @user.chores.each do |chore| %>
    <li><%= chore.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmmm... it's telling me, "Could not find the association :chorelist in model User"

Comment: But I have the 'through' syntax there.

Comment: Ah sorry about that! I updated the code snippet above to put in the missing association declarations. LMK how that goes

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, save for one caveat: after it lists the chores, it gives a block of all their data:

Comment: ""2016-11-03 16:33:54", updated_at: "2016-11-03 16:33:54", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>, #<Chore id: 2, name: "Mop Floors", created_at: "2016-11-03 16:33:54", updated_at: "2016-11-03 16:33:54", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>, #<Chore id: 3, name: "Laundry", created_at: "2016-11-03 16:33:54", updated_at: "2016-11-03 16:33:54", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>]"

Comment: Any idea why it might do that?

Comment: Replace `<%= user.chores.each %>` with `<% user.chores.each %>`. The former says "render the list" whereas the latter says "run this Ruby" and don't render anything